# sharing store data between extensions in JUNIT5

Tags: java, junit5

Is there anyway we can share data between different extensions in JUNIT 5 using store

Example

```
public class Extension1{
     beforeAllCallback(){
          getStore(GLOBAL).put(projectId,"112");
     }
}

public class Extension2{
     beforeTestExecutionCallback(){
          System.out.println("projectId="+getStore(GLOBAL).get(projectId));
     }
}
```

Comment: A very quick cursory search online suggest that a best practice of Junit 5 extensions is that they be *stateless*. Sharing data between them immediately violates that.  I suppose the real question is, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, two extensions can share state via the `Store` as follows.

Note, however, that you may wish to store the shared state in the *root* context `Store` if you want the state to be accessible across test classes.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeAllCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeTestExecutionCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.Namespace;

@ExtendWith({ Extension1.class, Extension2.class })
public class Tests {

    @Test
    void test() {
        // executing this results in the following being printed to SYS_OUT.
        // PROJECT_ID=112
    }
}

class Extension1 implements BeforeAllCallback {

    public static final String PROJECT_ID = Extension1.class.getName() + ".PROJECT_ID";

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        context.getStore(Namespace.GLOBAL).put(PROJECT_ID, "112");
    }
}

class Extension2 implements BeforeTestExecutionCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestExecution(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("PROJECT_ID=" + context.getStore(Namespace.GLOBAL).get(Extension1.PROJECT_ID));
    }
}
```