# JUnit5. How to share instance between to parameter resolvers?

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, junit5

## Hi

I have a `ParameterResolver`. It returns a `MyHttpClient` instance. It works. It's ok.

```java
public class HttpClientProvider implements ParameterResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return parameterContext.getParameter().getType().equals(MyHttpClient.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return new MyHttpClient();
    }
}
```

I want to create another one `ParameterResolver`. It should return an entity created by Http request. So to make a request, I need to provide a client. For now it's just a private field.

```java
public class EntityProvider implements ParameterResolver {
    private final MyHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient();

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        return parameterContext.getParameter().getType().equals(MyEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
            MyEntity item = client.create();
            return item;
    }
```

## The problem is

I have to create `MyHttpClient` twice: for `HttpClientProvider` and in `EntityProvider` (to make a create-request). This is code duplication.

## Question:

Is there any solution to call `HttpClientProvider:resolveParameter` from `EntityProvider` or *somehow* share one instance of `MyHttpClient` between two `ParameterResolver`'s?

## UPD. Solution for copy-pasting

Thanks to @johanneslink solution is using Storages.

How to share (HttpClientProvider)

```java
public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        MyHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient();
        extensionContext.getStore(Namespace.GLOBAL).put("client", client);
        return client;
    }
```

Ho to get (EntityProvider)

```java
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
        MyHttpClient client = (MyHttpClient)extensionContext.getStore(Namespace.GLOBAL).get("client");
        MyEntity item = client.create();
        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping state in extensions is done through what Jupiter calls "stores".
It's documented [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-keeping-state).

Another StackOverflow answers that describes the approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53142365/32352

What you should *never* do is use member variables in extensions and assume that the next invocation of the same extension will give you the same value back. The lifecycle of extension instances is mostly (and on purpose) undefined because it is context-dependent. Order of tests, concurrent test execution and nesting of test classes all play a role here.